# Managing elements of a dynamicly produced table

Tags: javascript, html

A button , onclick , adds a table row with three cells. In the first cell theres a textbox where you input an image url, the second cell contains a button.When pressed the button shows the image that the url refers to on the third cell.
Doing this for one row is simply, but i cant get it to work for subsequent rows because the id of each element would remain the same. 
I need some tips and ideas.

Code sample:

```
<script>
  var u = 1;


  function addRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById("t1");
    var row = table.insertRow(u);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


    cell1.innerHTML = '<input id="ur" type="url" >';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'im1\').src = document.getElementById(\'ur\').value;">Add Image</button>';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<img id="im1" src="" alt="image">';

    u++;
  }
</script>
```

Each row generates fine and if you put in a url or the name of a local image file it will display properly on the third cell.
But it only works on the first generated row.

Comment: You need to show some code of what you have done !

Comment: Show code as **text** not as **image**.

Comment: You may pass a param to addRows() function - param will be current ID. Inside the function you may take this param (current ID) and add random value, so that each time you will receive a new unique ID.

Comment: One should not use `id` for more than one element on a page. Also you can make use of dynamically generated `id` if you require so and get the value from the text

Comment: Duplicating JS code in each row is not a good way to begin with. If I were you (apart from the main issue), I would create a *single* listener for all the added buttons instead of adding an onclick event for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tab");
  
  var row          = document.createElement("tr");
  var buttonTd     = document.createElement("td");
  var button       = document.createElement("button");
  button.type      = "button";
  button.innerHTML = "Show image";
  buttonTd.appendChild(button);
  var textboxTd    = document.createElement("td");
  var textbox      = document.createElement("input");
  textbox.type     = "text";
  textboxTd.appendChild(textbox);
  var imageTd      = document.createElement("td");
  var image        = document.createElement("img");
  imageTd.appendChild(image);
  row.appendChild(textboxTd);
  row.appendChild(buttonTd);
  row.appendChild(imageTd);
  
  button.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    image.src = textbox.value;
  });
  
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table,tr,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

<table id="tab"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this sort of thing you shouldn't be calling and duplicating ids but instead relying on Sibling properties. Nevertheless a quick hack would be to use your increment variable to give unique ids to the elements.

```
var u = 1;


       function addRows(){
           var table = document.getElementById("t1");
           var row = table.insertRow(u);
           var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
           var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
           var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


           cell1.innerHTML = '<input id="ur'+u'" type="url" >' ;
           cell2.innerHTML = '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'im'+u'\').src = document.getElementById(\'ur'+u+'\').value;">Add Image</button>' ;
           cell3.innerHTML = '<img id="im'+u+'" src="" alt="image">' ;

           u++;
        }     
    </script>
```